# Decompile obfuscated jar file

Tags: decompilation, java, deobfuscation

Tried java-deobfuscator and other things, detect said it was allatori protected so tried the relevant transformers but to no avail.

Please can someone help, I'm happy to tip for your help :)

https://www.mediafire.com/file/s5rdv8gin4hcehi/osmb.jar/file

File in question.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/java-deobfuscator/deobfuscator/issues/254) might related

Comment: It didn't run :)

Answer (score 1):

The classes `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` show patterns matching that of [binscure](https://github.com/willemml/binscure), not Allatori. There are multiple open issues for *java-deobfuscator* on adding support for binscure, but there is no active development on the deobfuscator repo.

Additionally if you look around you'll find some code that looks like:

```
method public static a (Lcom/bC; a)Lcom/bC;
    getstatic 1.20 I
    ifge A
    invokedynamic while ()V handle H_INVOKESTATIC java/yeet.\u0020̸̸̷͔̻̠̖̼̖̅̍ͭ̈̋ͩ̈́͊̏ͬͬ̆̀̋̍͐͛ͣ͘|̔̽̔ͥ̆̑̀ͨ̈̒̿҉̪͙̭̠̻̹̗͍͇̞̟͙̫̝̟̀\u0020̸̥͔̭͈̈̈̾ͮ̃̾̾͛̀̍͐ͦ̾ͨ̍̉̓̈̚͝͝s̷ͨ̂̇ͨ̓́̋͗̈̒̑ͩ̆͊͏̩̯̩̙̝̯̣̪͉̳̘e̡͋̋̄̄ͧ̃ͪͨ͠͡҉̪̱̥̤͇̹͔͎̫͔̯͜ (I)V args  end
    invokedynamic fuck ()B handle H_INVOKESTATIC a.a (IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII)Ljava/lang/Throwable; args  end
    pop
A:
    aload a
    areturn
B:
end
```

The `yeet/fuck` names are hardcoded names used by some of [binscure's transformers](https://github.com/willemml/binscure/search?q=yeet).

So yeah, this isn't Allatori. What are your options *(at the time of writing this)*?

1. Write your own transformers *(either for java-deobfuscator or make your own project)*
2. Use [narumii's deobfuscator](https://github.com/narumii/Deobfuscator)

Be *VERY* careful when using narumii's deobfuscator. Only use it in a virtual machine, since it actually will attempt to load the classes to *"sandbox"* some of the decryption logic.